# Why does Deserialize stream throw unhandled exception when I try WinForm instead of CMD?

Tags: c#, winforms, deserialization

My code works well in a Console application. It saves a list of objects to a binary, reads the binary to a list and can update the data in the list.

I started a new WinForm project and try to replace my menusystem with buttons and input/output textfields. So far I start to run my different methods when clicking on the buttons.

```
Helpers.ListToConsole(Access.ReadBinaryToList());
```

Access.ReadBinaryToList() works fine to Console but the same code snippet throws an exception at `return (List<Quote>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);`

The complete code;

```
public static List<Quote> ReadBinaryToList()
    {
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\whoever\Desktop\Quotes\quotes.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            if (stream.Length == 0)
            {
                List<Quote> quoteList = new List<Quote>();// { new Quote(Guid.NewGuid(), "Quote dummy", false) };
                formatter.Serialize(stream, quoteList);
                //stream.Position = 0;
                return quoteList;
            }
            else return (List<Quote>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to be more specific than saying "unhandled exception". What was the type of the exception? What was the exception message? What was the stack trace?

Comment: HResult=-2146233076 I'm sorry. I am a complete newbie at this.

Comment: We need the type of the exception at "else return (List<Quote>...). Is it InvalidCastException? Is it SerializationException? What have you tried? If you use smaller steps: first Deserialize, and then Cast to List, when does the exception occur? What have you tried to find out what the problem is?

Comment: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: The `InnerException" of the `Exception` might tell you what went wrong. It looks like the data is not correct for deserialising `Quote`.